# nestjs integration test "Cannot set property "userId' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, integration-testing

I am starting to write end-to-end testing in nestjs. even the first simple test failed.

```
describe('Authentication system', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();
    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/(POST)', () => {
    const email = 'khfkjdhsf@hot';
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/signup')
      .send({ email, password: 'kasdhfkjdhfkj' })
      .expect(201)
      .then((res) => {
        const { id, email } = res.body;
        expect(id).toBeDefined();
      });
  });
});
```

this is controller:

```
@Post('/signup')
  async createUser(@Body() body: CreateUserDto, @Session() session: any) {
    const user = await this.authService.signUp(body.email, body.password);
    session.userId = user.id;
    return user;
  }
```

this is authService.signup:

```
async signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    const users = await this.usersService.find(email);
    if (users.length) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Email in use');
    }

    const salt = randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    const hash = (await scrypt(password, salt, 64)) as Buffer;
    const result = salt + '.' + hash.toString('hex');

    const user = await this.usersService.create(email, result);
    return user;
  }
```

I am using cookie-session for authentication in bootstrap():

```
 app.use(
    cookieSession({
      keys: ['anything'],
      }),
   );
```

when I send post request to `/signup` everything works fine. I believe testing logic is correct. I could not find answer on stackoverflow.

I also get this error under above error: "Expected 201, 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to set `userId` as well?

Comment: how do u authenticate the user

Comment: Are you sure you can use the express sessions in the testing environment? That could be the reason. Try to mock the session part.

Answer (score 2):

"app" is set in app module and then middlewares like cookie session are wired up with `app` in bootstrap(). We call bootstrap() and our app starts in development.

However, in a test environment, the main.ts file does not get executed. We are importing "app" into the test file. Look at the `beforeEach` hook:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
  }).compile();
  // this creates the next application out of the AppModule
  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  await app.init();
});
```

As you see there is no:

```js
app.use(
    cookieSession({
      keys: ['anything'],
      }),
   );
```

in test environment. cookie-session sets a "session" property on `request` object, since you did not set it in test environment, `req.session` is undefined. That is why you are gettin “Cannot set property ”userId' of undefined".

You can solve this in two ways. First way,create a function and wire up the middlewares:

```js
export const setupMiddlewares = (app: any) => {
  app.use(
    cookieSession({
      keys: ['anything'],
    }),
  );
  // you can add all middlewares or pipes
  );
};
```

Then call this in main.ts for development environment

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  // cookie-session is set
  setupMiddlewares(app);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and in testing file:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
  }).compile();
  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  // cookie-session is set
  setupMiddlewares(app);
  await app.init();
});
```

2'nd solution is set the cookie-session and all other middlewares within the app module itself. So when app module is executed, it will automatically set up the session middleware. in app.module.ts:

```js
export class AppModule {
  // this will be called automatically when your app start
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    // set up middleware that will run on every incoming request
    consumer
      .apply(
        cookieSession({
          keys: ['anything'],
        }),
        // this means we want to use this middleware for every incoming request
      )
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set up `cookieSession` in your `bootstrap`, but your `bootstrap` has **nothing** to do with you tests. You need to call the same `app.use()` in your test setup that you would in your `bootstrap` to have middleware parity, or move the middleware to a [Nest Middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) so you don't have to worry about this in the future.

```js
@Module(AppModuleMetadata)
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(
      cookieSeesion({
        keys: ['anything'],
      })
    );
  }
}
```